# Optional belongs_to and Rails routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, associations

I'm working on a **Rails 3** task demo project in which each instance of `Project` has many `tasks`, and instances of `Task` belong to one `project`. However, this latter relationship is optional, although it's defined in the `Task` model as `belongs_to :project`.

Essentially, I want to be able to have routes like the following:

```
example.com/tasks/1
example.com/tasks/new

example.com/project/1/tasks/1
example.com/project/1/tasks/new
```

I'm not sure if this is possible or even good practice. Really what's most important is for me to be able to create project-less tasks from within the general `tasks#index` action, and tasks belonging to a project from within the `project#show` action via links to `new` actions.

I've read [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), but it didn't really explain what I'm going for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually more common than you think. Here is a solution:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
before_filter :get_project
before_filter :get_tasks


  private

  def get_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id]) if params[:project_id]
  end

  def get_tasks
    @tasks = (@project) ? @project.tasks : Task
  end

end
```

From there you, you would always reference @tasks when you want to get the tasks.

So for an example:

```
def new
  @tasks.new(params[:task])
end
```

Would yield correct results whether you are nested or not.

In the case of nested, it would be like calling:

```
@projects.tasks.new(params[:task])
```

and without nested, it would be like calling:

```
Task.new(params[:task])
```

Comment: you could do: Project.tasks.create(params[:tasks].merge({:project_id=>params[:id]}) where params[:task] is just a hash that you would pass into #create.

Comment: Got it figured out with your advice, and tied it in with Devise. After setting up the routes, I really didn't have to change much else beyond what I originally had, other than that the new link_to tag is `link_to 'New Task', @project ? "#{@project.id}/tasks/new" : new_task_path`

Answer (score 0):

The routes do not relate with associations. You can have any routes you like, even if you do not have any associations. And your routes seem good.

The association is a convenience thing. It makes the programmer's life easier. If you even need to write something like :

```
task.projects
```

Then, you have to have a has_many(or other) association between tasks/projects. This has many is the one that allows you to do task.projects. If you did not have the association, you would have to use a finder.